# apache crash and mod_fcgi error

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, fastcgi

Apache crash with the following error :

```
mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5
mod_fcgid: /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 spawn score 10 >= 10, skip the spawn request
mod_fcgid: too many /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 processes (current:10, max:10), skip the spawn request
mod_fcgid: process /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5(22777) exit(communication error), get unexpected signal 11
```

I have cPanel installed on my Centos5, Apache v2.2.22 , PHP v5.2.17

php.conf contents :

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
FcgidMaxProcesses 10
FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 10
FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 1
FcgidIOTimeout 300
FcgidFixPathinfo 1 
FcgidIdleTimeout 100
FcgidIdleScanInterval 30
FcgidBusyTimeout 300
FcgidBusyScanInterval 30
FcgidErrorScanInterval 3
FcgidZombieScanInterval 3
FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
FcgidMaxRequestInMem 419430400
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
```

I have the same error on many servers with the same config.

Answer (score 2):

> spawn score 10 >= 10, skip the spawn request

View **FcgidSpawnScoreUpLimit** directive:
http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidspawnscoreuplimit

Possibly, your modfcgid is spawning several processes and with this limit chop requests for caution.